# Comparar dos campos de entrada c# CompareValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

tengo un formulario que contiene dos campos `input`, uno para el correo electrónico y otro para reingresar el correo y validar que sean iguales, para esto último utilizo el CompareValidator pero no me despliega el error al momento de cambiar foco hacia el botón de enviar

El siguiente es el campo de Correo electrónico

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" Text="Correo electrónico" ToolTip="Correo electrónico" runat="server" /><span class="campoObligatorio">*</span>
<input id="txtCorreo" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Ej: juan.perez@dominio.com" title="Correo electrónico" runat="server" autocomplete="off" validationgroup="vgrCapturaDatos" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCorreo" CssClass="errorCaptura" ValidationGroup="vgrCapturaDatos" Text=" " ErrorMessage="El Correo electrónico es obligatorio" ControlToValidate="textoCorreo" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexEmailValid" CssClass="errorCaptura" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vgrCapturaDatos" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ControlToValidate="textoCorreo" Text=" " ErrorMessage="Formato de correo no valido"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

El siguiente es el campo para ser validado

```
<asp:Label ID="Label6" Text="Valide su Correo electrónico" ToolTip="Correo electrónico" runat="server" /><span class="campoObligatorio">*</span>
<input id="txtValidaCorreo" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Ej: juan.perez@dominio.com" title="Valida correo electrónico" runat="server" autocomplete="off" validationgroup="vgrCapturaDatos"/>
```

y el siguiente es el validador para comparar

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cfvNumeroCelular" runat="server"  ControlToCompare="txtCorreo" ControlToValidate="txtValidaCorreo" Operator="Equal" Type="Integer" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="vgrCapturaDatos" ErrorMessage="El valor ingresado no coincide." ></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Sin embargo cuando paso el foco a el siguiente control o envio el formulario, no hace la validación y pasa derecho así los valores sean diferentes. Agradezco de su ayuda y colaboración para poder saber en donde tengo el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en el compare validator.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cfvNumeroCelular" runat="server"  ControlToCompare="txtCorreo" ControlToValidate="txtValidaCorreo" Operator="Equal" Type="Integer" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="vgrCapturaDatos" ErrorMessage="El valor ingresado no coincide." ></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Tienes puesto **Type="Integer"**. Cambialo por **Type="String"**. Porque estas comparando cadenas, no enteros.

También deberías de poner Display="Static", más que nada para que esté como los demás.

En el botón que hace submit pon también esto ValidationGroup="vgrCapturaDatos" para asegurarte que hace la validación de ese grupo.

Te dejo un ejemplo de código donde funciona correctamente:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CompareValidator" ControlToCompare="TextBox2" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="vgrCapturaDatos"></asp:CompareValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="vgrCapturaDatos"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="vgrCapturaDatos" />
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Edité la respuesta. Prueba con lo que te propongo.

Comment: Jaime, tenias razón, muchas gracias

Comment: La situación es la siguiente: si damos cuenta del código anexo el campo de validación tiene un `label`, un `input` y un `CompareValidation` este funciona de forma correcta si en el `input`se ingresan datos, si el `input` esta vacio no hace validación por lo cual he debido incluir un `RequiredFieldValidator`